# Determine position of a smallest value in multiple cells?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

To find a row position of smallest value in a range I would simply do:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim dblMin As Double

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
dblMin = Application.Match(Application.Min(rng), rng, 0)

End Sub
```

How to check specific cells A1, A3 and A6 instead and also adjust my range?

I tried something like `Min(A1,A3,A6)` and how can I change the lookup range? `A1&A3&A6 or A1,A3,A6` doesn't work...

Ideally I would like to return the row position 1 or 2 or 3, because we are only comparing 3 values.

Comment: `Range("A1,A3,A6")` will find the minimum but don't think it will work in the match. You might need a loop.

Comment: `=IF(MIN(A1,A3,A6)=A1,1,IF(MIN(A1,A3,A6)=A3,2,3))`

Comment: @ForwardEd this can work for now, so to add the formula into the code would it be something like this? `dblMin = IF(MIN(A1,A3,A6)=A1,1,IF(MIN(A1,A3,A6)=A3,2,3))`?

Comment: What I wrote is an excel formula since you had tag the question with excel-formula.  I left it as a comment instead of an answer because you had shown VBA in the question...that and my VBA skills are weak.  In VBA I would do it ather as a series of nested IF statments or potentially CASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like the code below:

```
Dim Rng As Range, FindRng As Range
Dim dblMin As Double

' set the Range
Set Rng = Application.Union(Sheet1.Range("A1"), Sheet1.Range("A3"), Sheet1.Range("A6"))

' find the minimum value
dblMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(Rng)

' use Find to find the Minimum value in your range
Set FindRng = Rng.Find(what:=dblMin, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

MsgBox "Minimum found at " & FindRng.Address(False, False, xlA1)
```

---

***Edit 1*** - get the order of the cell inside the range

***Modified Code***

```
Dim Rng As Range, C As Range
Dim dblMin As Double, i As Long, MatchRow As Variant
Dim Arr() As Double

' set the Range
Set Rng = Application.Union(Sheet1.Range("A1"), Sheet1.Range("A3"), Sheet1.Range("A6"))

' populate Array from values in Range
ReDim Arr(1 To Rng.Cells.Count)
i = 1
For Each C In Rng
    Arr(i) = C.Value
    i = i + 1
Next C

' find the minimum value
dblMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(Rng)

' use Match to find the element order inside the array
MatchRow = Application.Match(dblMin, Arr, 0)

MsgBox MatchRow
```

Comment: Instead of returning address, How do I return it as 1 or 2 or 3 because we are only looking at Min of 3 values? I'm trying to find a position of a row

Comment: @ggmkp you want to get back the number of the row ? or the number of the cell inside the range ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I suspect neither.  more like if the min is A1 then 1, if A3 then 2 otherwise A6 is min and value of 3.  The better question is what happens in the event of a tie

Comment: @ForwardEd you are exactly right, for a tie it would be the first cell, same behavior as `Match` function

Comment: @ggmkp I would say take this code by Shai Rado and change that last line about rng.find and try your Application.match on the rng that was the union of your separate cells and see if that works for you.

Comment: @ShaiRado I'm studying the code to understand what's going on. But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code:

```
    Dim rng1 as Range
    Dim rng2 as Range
    Dim rng3 as Range

    Dim lMin as Double

    Set rng1 = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    Set rng2 = Sheet1.Range("A2")
    Set rng3 = Sheet1.Range("A6")

    lMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng1.Value, rng2.Value, rng3.Value)

    Select Case lMin
        Case is = rng1
            Debug.Print "The range rng1 contains the smallest value."
            ' You can insert code here to do something when rng1 is minimum...

        Case is = rng2
            Debug.Print "The range rng2 contains the smallest value."
            ' You can insert code here to do something when rng2 is minimum...

        Case is = rng3
            Debug.Print "The range rng3 contains the smallest value."
            ' You can insert code here to do something when rng3 is minimum...
    End Select
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the CASE option.  I am not that familiar with it, so its a good learning opportunity for me to read it.

Comment: It's actually very simple and you don't need to have multiple 'If-then' statements or nesting. Good luck!

Comment: its more the syntax when you are not used to using it.  Like I know now there is an ELSE case which at the one time I did not know existed so I was often hesitant to use it

Answer (score 0):

```
IF Application.min(rng) = Sheet1.range("A1").value then
    dblMin = 1
Else If Application.min(rng) = sheet1.range("A3").value then
    dblMin = 2
Else
    dblMin = 3
End If
```

Have not tested syntax.  Would be the general concept of nested IF to text if a cell was equal to the minimum.